# Logout function in QWebView

Tags: c++, session, qt4, qwebview, qwebkit

I'm developing application in Qt 4.8.1.
I trying to develope a simple web browser. I want to create function logout on site.

As I understand the required information is stored in cookies.
In `webView->page()->networkAccessManager()->cookieJar()` I have not found clearing cookies.
May be the session must be closed. Isn't?
Help me to create the logout function.

Comment: QWebView is pretty much already a simple web browser. And normally web browsers do not logout users from web sites.

Comment: This is implemented on the server side, not on the client. In other words, QWebView has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If you close the webView, and then open a new webView on the same site, then the session will be closed.
How can this be achieved without closing webView?

Comment: @NeedForS this depends how session is implemented. For most of server-side sessions this won't happen until session timeout will be reached. For most of cookie-based ones this won't happen too until cookies are expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try delete the webpage object of the webview and instantiate a newPage object. and then `webView->setPage(newPage);`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to simulate a logout using Javascript evaluation on the webPage->page()->mainFrame() object. For example, you could make a function like this to log out:

```
void Program::logout()
{
    webView->page()->mainFrame->evaluateJavaScript("websiteLogoutJavaScript();");
}
```

Of course, change the JS in the evaluate call to match the logout process. This method will depend on how to physically logout of the website. If it's a button, you could invoke a click event on the button. If it's a hyperlink that goes to a logout page, you could just navigate to the logout page. These are just some suggestions, but you will need to change the state of the DOM using JavaScript.